# bold part of string in UITextView swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

Here is the text:

```
@IBOutlet weak var legalText: UITextView!
let textToAppend = "TERMS OF SERVICE\nLast Updated: May 7, 2015\n\nPLEASE NOTE: The HIGO Terms of Service as stated below is effective as of the 'Last Updated' date above for any user who is browsing the HIGO website, or for any user who creates a HIGO account on or after that date."
legalText.text = legalText.text.stringByAppendingString(textToAppend)
```

i want to bold "TERMS OF SERVICE" and "PLEASE NOTE: The HIGO Terms of Service as stated below is effective as of the 'Last Updated' date above for any user who is browsing the HIGO website, or for any user who creates a HIGO account on or after that date."

i try with use uilabel programmatically in uitextview but did not work :

```
var termsofservice : UILabel = UILabel()
termsofservice.numberOfLines = 0
termsofservice.text = "TERMS OF SERVICE"
termsofservice.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
termsofservice.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;

var pleasenote : UILabel = UILabel()
pleasenote.numberOfLines = 0
pleasenote.text = "PLEASE NOTE: The HIGO Terms of Service as stated below is effective as of the 'Last Updated' date above for any user who is browsing the HIGO website, or for any user who creates a HIGO account on or after that date."
pleasenote.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
pleasenote.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;

let textToAppend = "\(termsofservice)\nLast Updated: May 7, 2015\n\n\(pleasenote)"
```

also try with these but did not work, it only show "TERMS OF SERVICE" and "last update..", did not show "PLEASE NOTE..."

```
var termsofservice = "TERMS OF SERVICE"
var normalText = "\n\nLast Updated: May 7, 2015"
var pleasenote  = "\n\nPLEASE NOTE: The HIGO Terms of Service as stated below is effective as of the 'Last Updated' date above for any user who is browsing the HIGO website, or for any user who creates a HIGO account on or after that date."

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:normalText)

var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]
var boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:pleasenote, attributes:attrs)
var boldString0 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:termsofservice, attributes:attrs)

boldString0.appendAttributedString(attributedString)
attributedString.appendAttributedString(boldString)
legalText.attributedText = boldString0
```

How to bold that part of string?

Note:the text is still long and have more part of string to bold.

Comment: You should use attributed string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making text bold using attributed string in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496093/making-text-bold-using-attributed-string-in-swift)

Comment: how? please show me.

Comment: Of course your second code won't show the pleasant bit. You are appending it to the wrong string.

Comment: `attributedString.appendAttributedString(boldString)` to `boldString0.appendAttributedString(boldString)`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
func attributedText() -> NSAttributedString {

    let string = "TERMS OF SERVICE\nLast Updated: May 7, 2015\n\nPLEASE NOTE: The HIGO Terms of Service as stated below is effective as of the 'Last Updated' date above for any user who is browsing the HIGO website, or for any user who creates a HIGO account on or after that date." as NSString

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)])

    let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)]

    // Part of string to be bold
    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: string.range(of: "TERMS OF SERVICE"))
    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: string.range(of: "PLEASE NOTE:"))

    // 4
    return attributedString
}
```

And set attributext text to your text view as:

```
legalText.attributedText = attributedText()
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but `rangeOfString` returns `Range`, and `addAttributes` needs a `NSRange`, so you need to play with it a little bit. Anyway, +1

Comment: If you'll use string as NSString `rangeOfString` will return NSRange, hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: There is no error, the string just doesn't render the NSFontAttributeName that i provided.

Comment: For Swift 4:
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)])
        let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)]

Answer (score 11):

Better still, you can go ahead and use this 1 function in your armoury, in a file like Constants.swift and then you can embolden words within any string, on numerous occasions by calling just **ONE LINE** of code:

To go in a file without a class, like constants.swift in my case:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

func addBoldText(fullString: NSString, boldPartOfString: NSString, font: UIFont!, boldFont: UIFont!) -> NSAttributedString {
    let nonBoldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:font!]
    let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:boldFont!]
    let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString as String, attributes:nonBoldFontAttribute)
    boldString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: fullString.range(of: boldPartOfString as String))
    return boldString
}
```

Then you can just call this one line of code for any UILabel:

```
let normalFont = UIFont(name: "INSERT FONT NAME", size: 14)
let boldFont = UIFont(name: "INSERT BOLD FONT NAME", size: 14)
self.UILabel.attributedText = addBoldText("Check again in 30 DAYS to find more friends", boldPartOfString: "30 DAYS", font: normalFont!, boldFont: boldFont!)
```

Comment: I know this is old, but is there a way to use this to bold two separate parts of the same string?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2 Update**

```
func addBoldText(fullString: String, boldPartOfString: String, baseFont: UIFont, boldFont: UIFont) -> NSAttributedString {

    //1
    let baseFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : baseFont]
    let boldFontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : boldFont]

    //2
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString, attributes: baseFontAttribute)

    //3. Note if 'boldPartOfString' is not a substring of 'fullString', enitre 'fullString' will be formatted with 'boldFont'
    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: NSRange(fullString.range(of: boldPartOfString) ?? fullString.startIndex..<fullString.endIndex, in: fullString))

    //4
    return attributedString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Update** (from the answer of @Hamza Ansari)

```
func attributedText()-> NSAttributedString
{
    let string = "TERMS OF SERVICE\nLast Updated: May 7, 2015\n\nPLEASE NOTE: The HIGO Terms of Service as stated below is effective as of the 'Last Updated' date above for any user who is browsing the HIGO website, or for any user who creates a HIGO account on or after that date." as NSString

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)])

    let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)]

    // Part of string to be bold
    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: string.range(of: "TERMS OF SERVICE"))
    attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: string.range(of: "PLEASE NOTE:"))

    // 4
    return attributedString
}
```