# How to set San francisco font for labels inside a Custom Cell for tableView

Tags: swift3

I have a custom cell for a tableView in which I have added a few labels. for this custom cell I also created a Swift file for it.

Say, I have the following labels:

LabelShop
 LabelAddress
 LabelZipcode

Problem: 
How to set up San Francisco Font for these Lables which inside the custom cell? Set up inside the ViewController?

```
Example:

LabelShop.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21.0 , weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
```

Please kindly extend your assistance.

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396260/in-swift-how-can-i-change-an-attribute-of-part-of-a-string/46398951#46398951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup this font from 
`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function in view controller or directly from cell itself in `awakeFromNib`.

This code should be sufficient: `label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21.0 , weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)`.

First approach:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YOURCELLIDENTIFIER, for: indexPath)

   if let castedCell = cell as? YourCellClass {
       castedCell.label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21.0, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
   }

   return cell
}
```

Second:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21.0 , weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
}
```

Comment: Is this means I need to create @IBOutlet for all the labels in Custom Cell inside the UIViewController or the Swift file for Custom Cell?

Comment: You should connect outlets in custom cell class, yes.