# How to change color of text strings inside UITextView in Swift3

Tags: ios, textview, swift3

I have looked at some existing questions posts here and I tried to implement all code but ended up not being able to successfully implement any code. Actually, I think I comprehended how to change colors of some texts inside `UITextView` if a text is initially set, but what I do not understand is that when my `UITextView` began entering editing, it does not seem to be working properly at all. In the following, it is my attempted code that closely full fills my desired behaviour.

```
 func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let main_string = ""
    let getData: [String] = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myData") as! [String]
    print("\(getData)")

    let searchWords = "world"

        let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: searchWords)

        let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: main_string)
        attribute.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red , range: range)

        mytextView.attributedText = attribute


}
```

I saved input data by naming `MyData`. I tried to use a for-loop to take all elements out of `getData` and use it as individual values. However, in the console, there are so many lines of explanation. I think this is a proper way to write, but my mac says nooooooo. However, If I set a `String` inside `main_string` and `searchWords`, for example, *"this is my question. I want people to help me from the world"* in main_string and *"world"* in searchWords as written in the code. Then after the app is being loaded, on my text view the word, "world" is highlighted in red perfectly, but after the world word, all text is in red. I do not understand why I am being tortured by this unknown bug.

So What I want to accomplish is

1. from the saved date in my `myData`, I only want the stored words to be highlighted timely when users type in. For example, if a user types "hello" and "world". Then they are saved by `myData` and they are going to be highlighted only when typed. And switch back to the normal color when words which are not stored are typed.

I assume I lack some explanation. If you need to know something, please point out for me. Thanks very much!!

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In this I have taken string "world" as example. When you r typing in textview then This method is in working**

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string:txtview.text)
        let inputLength = attrStr.string.characters.count
        let searchString = "world"
        let searchLength = searchString.characters.count
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: searchString, options: [], range: range)
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                textView.attributedText = attrStr
            }
        }    
}
```

**But when You have already set initial text of textview then use this method**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        //Just set your text as you set in textview
        let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello world I ma jeckjklwefljlwjflkjwfkljelwfjklfgjwklfjlkwgjwlgkjwklsgjklsjgklsdjgkljdslkgjsdlkgjlksdjgldjsgldjskl world nsfhjklshfklhsllsd fgiw world")
        let inputLength = attrStr.string.characters.count
        let searchString = "world"
        let searchLength = searchString.characters.count
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: searchString, options: [], range: range)
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                textView.attributedText = attrStr
            }
          }  
  }
```

**For Multiple Strings, You can do like this SWIFT 3**

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: txtview.text)
        let inputLength = attrStr.string.characters.count
        let searchString : NSArray = NSArray.init(objects: "hello","world")
        for i in 0...searchString.count-1
        {

             let string : String = searchString.object(at: i) as! String
             let searchLength = string.characters.count
             var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

             while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                 range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: string, options: [], range: range)
                 if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                 attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                 range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
                 textView.attributedText = attrStr
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

**OBJECTIVE C**
**For Multiple Strings, You can do like this**

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attstr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textView.text];
    NSUInteger characterCount = [attstr length];
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"football",@"player",nil];

    for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {

    NSUInteger searchlength = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]] length];
    NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(0, attstr.length);

    while (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        range1 =[attstr.string rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]] options:0 range:range1];
        if (range1.location !=NSNotFound) {
            [attstr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(range1.location, searchlength)];
            [attstr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]  range:range1];
            range1 = NSMakeRange(range1.location + range1.length, characterCount -(range1.location + range1.length));
            textView.attributedText = attstr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much. But I have one more question. If there are several words in a String array, how am I able to implement such code?

Comment: @ryohei I will update my answer with your question but according to your very first question, My answer is perfect, So please approve for others

Comment: @ryohei I have updated my answer with your requirement Like I have Multiple strings and I have to change color of all occurences

Comment: Ok, Just wait for it. I will change it to swift but If its  working in swift you have to approve my answer

Comment: Okay, I approved it but it is not working for me... So I appreciate your change into Swift thanks

Comment: @ryohei Ok, I have updated my answer and its working 100%. Thank you

Comment: There seems to be two issues. Btw I put the code inside textViewDidBeginEditing. First, when I use data saved in my userdefaults, it gets crashed. My assumption of this reason is that I did not use for-loop, true? Second, my initial font size value of my text view is 18, and when I add "hello" + additional random words, nothing changes, but after duoble click on the return key on my keyborad, the font size changes to the default. Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126387/discussion-between-jecky-and-ryohei).

Comment: Is it possible to highlight words in multiple colors?

Comment: Means What do you want to achieve, I dont understand ?

Comment: Like I tried to put nested array like [[String]], but it failed. I have several arrays and I want to highlight all words stored in those arrays

Comment: Inside the textview

Comment: Please come inside discussion