# Reset attributes of attributedText in textView when clearing it - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a textView that contains an editable text (its color and font attributes are set by the user) I implemented an attributedText in order to achieve this, but when the textView is emptied (there's no text in it) the attributes are still the ones chosen before. i.e. if red color is chosen, when all text is deleted and if new text is typed it keeps the red color, I want this new text to have the default values of color and font. I have tried to set the attributedText to nil, but I don't know how to indicate that the textView has no text, I have the following code in a UITextView extension:

```
 func setAttributedValueAtSelectedTextRange(_ attributeName: String, value: Any) {
    let textRange = selectedRange
    let selectedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
    selectedText.addAttribute(attributeName, value: value, range: textRange)
    attributedText = selectedText
    selectedRange = textRange
    attributedText = nil
}
```

Comment: check if noteTextView.text == " "

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Marilyn.. what is the issue? is it not going in the if condition or not changing the font?

Comment: please print textview.text and check that if you getting anything or not becuase it is also possible that you are getting white space into it

Comment: @DheerajD the method above changes the color attribute of some text in a UITextView. When the textView is emptied (all text is deleted) and some new text is typed, it has the old color attribute, i'm trying to set this attribute to its default value (black color) and add it to the new text.

Comment: @Jecky I think my code doesn't work because when I type a new character (or any new text) the text in the textView is no longer nothing or "" so it has the old chosen color instead of the black color set in the condition.

Comment: Make a bool indicate if the textview has been clear or not, then use it to know which attribute to use

Comment: please check my answer Hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149122/how-to-change-color-of-text-stirngs-inside-uitextview-in-swift3/40151850#40151850

Comment: I am having same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766757/uitextview-text-color-doesnt-reset-after-setting-attributed-text

Answer (score 3):

The attributes that will be applied to newly-typed text come from the `typingAttributes` property. That gets changed automatically when text is selected, so the new text matches what is replaced or, if the selection is empty, what precedes it.

In your case, you can just set it to an empty dictionary to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the attributes back to default when you determine the right point. Ie. `textField.textColor = UiColor.black`