# Changed color of a substring but the font setting is reset

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextview

[How to change color of text stirngs inside UITextView in Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149122/how-to-change-color-of-text-stirngs-inside-uitextview-in-swift3)

I tried to change the colour of the substring like this referencing the above url.

[image]

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView, pageIndex: Int) {
    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
    let inputLength = attrStr.string.characters.count
    let searchString = self.emphasisingWordList[pageIndex]
    let searchLength = searchString.characters.count
    var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)

    while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: searchString, options: [], range: range)
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orange, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
            range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
            textView.attributedText = attrStr
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found the font size and colour are reset to default (black) when the attributed text is set.

I added those lines in the end of the code but of course the whole string would be effected.

```
self.sloganTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 35)
self.sloganTextView.textColor = UIColor.white
```

Is there any good solution or do I have to change each attribute colour one by one?

As many people have already mentioned, selectable is set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
var strName: String = "ABC"
var strTitle: String = "XYZ"
let commentString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: strTitle + " \(strName)")
commentString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (strTitle.characters.count )))
commentString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.orange, range: NSRange(location: (strTitle.characters.count ), length: (strName.characters.count ) + 1))
self.txtView.attributedText = commentString
```

Hope this code help you.