# Color up text in textview within a specific range

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview

I'm new to iOS development. 
How to color up the text in UITextView within a specific range given?
For example: 
ABCDEFG ** iOS ** 1234567 **
I just want to make the text within ** (iOS and 1234567) into red color. 
What is the best solution to deal with this problem and I'm using Swift 3?
Thanks!!

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39640057/4601900