# How to specify title color for individual navigation bars? Swift

Tags: swift, colors, navigation

So say that I have 3 view controllers, A, B, and C.

A has a black background, B a white and C a blue.

All of these use `NavigationControllerBars` to navigate.

How do I programmatically change the color of the navBar title on these?

So that I have a white title on A, black for B and maybe Red for C.

From what I've gathered everyone uses for example:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

I'm new to swift but to me that looks like Obj-C?

That doesn't work for me and I keep getting

> Replace 'NSForegroundColorAttributeName' with
>   'NSForegroundColorAttributeName.rawValue'

as an error.

Comment: Learn how to use NSAttributedString.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing specific text's color using NSMutableAttributedString in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207373/changing-specific-texts-color-using-nsmutableattributedstring-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my code and it compiled without any problem.

**Swift 2.3**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

**Swift 3**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```