# How to change text color of NSTextView

Tags: swift

How can I change the color of all text in a NSTextView? In the example below, `myTextView.textColor = .white` only changes color of `Hello` but not `World`. I don't want to specify the color every time when I append some text.

Also I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way appending text to NSTextView.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTextView.string = "Hello"
        myTextView.backgroundColor = .black
        myTextView.textColor = .white

        logTextView.textStorage?.append(NSAttributedString(string: "World"))
    }
```

Comment: check adding attribute with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` for you `NSAttributedString` [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207373/changing-specific-texts-color-using-nsmutableattributedstring-in-swift)

Comment: myTextView only has the string "Hello". you are appending attributed text to logTextView. When using Swift it's best to stick to Swift bridged classes. use UITextView instead of NSTextView

Comment: It's a macOS app

Answer (score 1):

`NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString` so you can manipulate it as a mutable attributed string.

**If you want the new text to carry on the attributes at the end of the current text**, append to the mutable string:

```
myTextView.textStorage?.mutableString.append("World")
```

**If you want to add more attributes to the new text (for example, adding an underline)**, get the attributes at the end of the current text and manipulate the attributes dictionary:

```
guard let textStorage = myTextView.textStorage else {
    return
}
var attributes = textStorage.attributes(at: textStorage.length - 1, effectiveRange: nil)
attributes[.underlineStyle] = NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue)

textStorage.append(NSAttributedString(string: "World", attributes: attributes))
```

After this, if you call `mutableString.append`, the new text will be in white and underlined.