# Apply different attributes on UILabel.attributedText on the go

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm using Swift 4, with Xcode 9.2.

I have a `UILabel`, which in their `.attributedText` property I have associated an `NSMutableAttributedString`. In fact, this `NSMutableAttributedString` is made from the concatenation of two different `NSMutableAttributedString`, everyone with different attributes.

Since using `append()` I merge all `NSMutableAttributedString` in a single mutable string, how can I retrieve the range of the attributes I have previously set before appending everything (probably it can't be done)? Or, there is a way to place more than a `NSMutableAttributedString` inside the `UILabel.attributedText`? Or, again, can I get this behaviour without using a `UILabel` (maybe using a `UITextView`, for example)?

This is the problem I encountered because I need to add a `UISwitch` that hides (= restore it to default black) and shows again the `foregroundColor` of this `NSMutableAttributedString` on the go, but since only a part of this string has a `foregroundColor` attribute, I can't simply apply the attribute on the whole string.

This is the code:

```
func attributedTest (_ testString : String)
{
    // the first NSMutableAttributedString created
    let firstString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: testString,
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(
            name: "Futura",
            size: 20.0)!])

    // the second NSMutableAttributedString created, they're equal
    let secondString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: testString,
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(
            name: "Futura",
            size: 20.0)!])

    // here I'm adding the attributed on test2
    // the NSRange, in this case, is equal to the whole string
    secondString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRangeFromString("0, \(testString.count)"))

    // here I'm appending the second string to the first one
    firstString.append(secondString)

    // here I'm setting the testLabel.attributedText
    testLabel.attributedText = test
}
```

I thought of a plain copy of this `NSMutableAttributedString`, with no attributes at all (the `UIFont` is external to the attribute so I'm not worried), stored somewhere. Can having these two strings and switch them on the go when needed through the `UISwitch` be a decent solution (not optimal, though)?

Thank you!

Comment: U can get range from here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207373/changing-specific-texts-color-using-nsmutableattributedstring-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
     NSString *str = @"your string here";
     NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};
     NSAttributedString *newAttStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:attributes];
    [mutableAttStr appendAttributedString:newAttStr];
    testLabel.attributedText = mutableAttStr;
```

Comment: I don't have problems in creating and appending NSMutableAttributedStrings, in fact my code works very well with that. My problem is how to know where attributes are already applied to the string, and delete / restore them on the go

Comment: You can set range to your string and append final string to mutable object. like  " [mutableAttStr addAttribute:str value:[UIColor grayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)] "