# Replace character in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

This works for a regular `NSString`:

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

But there is no such method for `NSMutableAttributedString`. How could I remove all instances of a comma in an `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Answer (score 7):

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello <b>friend<b>")

attrString.mutableString.replaceOccurrencesOfString("<b>", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it before you create the attributed string, if you can or depending on how you source it. If you can't then you can use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` (or `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:`), but you need to know the range so you need to search and iterate yourself.

Comment: I already have the attributed string. It may include text attachments, etc. I know I have to use replaceCharactersInRange:withString but like you said, I don't know the ranges.

Comment: That's why you would preferentially 'fix' the string first. You can get the `string` - the plain version of the attributed string - and find the range of the target string. But, you need to get it on each iteration as you'll be mutating the original string, or track the mutation range...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *newString= "I want to ,show, you how to achieve this";
NSMutableAttributedString *displayText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newString]];
[[displayText mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, displayText.string.length)];
```

Comment: The first version didn't work, because you assigned an immutable string to newString. The second version: Why on earth are you using stringWithFormat?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the attributed string with the stripped string with the designed init. No?

Answer (score 0):

The code could be applied from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231240/replace-substring-of-nsattributedstring-with-another-nsattributedstring):

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = ...;
NSAttributedString *anotherAttributedString = ...; //the string or characters which will replace

while ([attributedString.mutableString containsString:@"replace"]) {
        NSRange range = [attributedString.mutableString rangeOfString:@"replace"];
        [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:range  withAttributedString:anotherAttributedString];
    }
```