# NSAttributedString has no member replacingOccurrences error

Tags: swift, string, uitextview, nsattributedstring

This is my code

```
class AmDocViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {
    var text1:String!
    let replaceYName: String = "text1"

    var textA:String!
    let replaceFName: String = "textA"

    var textB:String!
    let replaceyGFName: String = "textB"

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextView.delegate = self;
        self.view.endEditing(true)

 let notes37 = NSAttributedString(string:"""
(SOME SAMPLE TEXT......)
""", attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray])

 let newMutableString77 = notes37.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
        newMutableString77.append(notes37)

myTextView.attributedText = newMutableString77 as NSAttributedString

        let originalString = myTextView.text

        let updatedString = originalString?.replacingOccurrences(of: replaceYName, with: text1)
        let updatedString1 = updatedString?.replacingOccurrences(of: replaceFName, with: textA)

        if textB == "" {
            let updatedString2 = updatedString1?.replacingOccurrences(of: str25, with: "N/A")
        }
        if textB != ""{
            let updatedString2 = updatedString1?.replacingOccurrences(of: replaceyGFName, with: textB)
        }

        myTextView.text = updatedString2

        myTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }
```

Getting below error message in the if statement lines

```
Argument type 'NSAttributedString' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'
```

Please advice how to use the String value received from other ViewController TextField(text1) and replace a attributed String in a TextView ?

Comment: You need to give more infos: What line is creating this error? What the class of the objects? Because I don't see NSAttributedString in your question, I guess that `replaceyGFName` is a NSAttributedString and not a String? It's clearly unclear.

Comment: Find the occurence ranges (with regex or loop), then use `replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with str: String)` on each of the ranges. `NSMutableAttributedString` doesn't have a `replacingOccurrences()` equivalent. (Edit, I removed my previous downvote because now, even if you code is messy in my personal opinion, it gives more infos and important one concerning your issue).

Comment: Thanks and may be messy and learning thro mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**
A StringProtocol defined by apple documentation:

> A type that can represent a string as a collection of characters.

Im assuming that the variable  `str25` is an `NSAttributedString` This is the cause of your error. Ensure that the variable you pass into `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` is of Type `String`

Another route you could take is to convert your `String` into an `NSMutableAttributedString`, this object has a `var mutableString: NSMutableString { get }` property that

> returns The mutable string object

Then you can use this in your `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` method

Comment: If I change into String, I will loose the attributes Correct? I want to retain

Comment: Yes, use the other method if you want to keep your attributes , change to `NSMutableAttributedString `

Comment: Will it be possible to correct or advice my above code? Searched/tried and not successful so dar

Comment: used this code`let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello <b>friend<b>")

attrString.mutableString.replaceOccurrencesOfString("<b>", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))` from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635950/replace-character-in-nsmutableattributedstring] no issues now. Thanks