# ReplaceCharactersInRange of NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I want to replace a substring (e.g. @"replaceString") of an NSAttributedString (which contains NSTextAttachments in it) with another NSAttributedString.

I have tried to work with the mutableString of NSMutableAttributedString, but result is omitting the NSTextAttachments in it. The answer below doesn't work with my case.

[Replace substring of NSAttributedString with another NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231240/replace-substring-of-nsattributedstring-with-another-nsattributedstring)

Comment: `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:`? Or do you have an example of the initial `NSAttributedString`, replacement, end wanted final one?

Comment: 'replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString' worked . Thanks