# Remove part of attributed string without removing attributes

Tags: swift

I have some text in my attributed string that I am trying to remove. How can I do this without removing the attributes?

What I've tried:

I found this post on SO ([Replace substring of NSAttributedString with another NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231240/replace-substring-of-nsattributedstring-with-another-nsattributedstring)) where OP is looking for the equivalent method to NSString's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: for NSAttributedString. I am new to Swift so I couldn't understand the accepted answer.

I moved on to the other answers and if they weren't written in objective c, they were methods that I could not get to compile.

This is as far as I have been able to get. I couldn't find any other posts on SO with a solution to my problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Comment: I have but cannot figure out if what I am trying to do is possible.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: You don't need to look for other answers. Look at the documentation. There is a clear method for removing part of a mutable attributed string. You just need a range.

Comment: I could be mistaken @mschmidt. I apologize I am new to Swift. Do you know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove part of an attributed string you need to use the `NSMutableAttributedString deleteCharacters(in:)` method.

Here's some sample code:

```
// Create some attributes string
let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [ .foregroundColor: UIColor.red, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24) ]
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello there", attributes: attrs)
print(attrStr)

// Create a mutable attributed string, find the range to remove and remove it
let mutStr = attrStr.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
let range = (mutStr.string as NSString).range(of: " there")
mutStr.deleteCharacters(in: range)
print(mutStr)
```

Output:

```
Hello there{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f989541d6c0> font-family: \".SFUIDisplay\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt";
}
Hello{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f989541d6c0> font-family: \".SFUIDisplay\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt";
}
```